# Size of a collectd packet

Tags: collectd

Can anyone help me find the size of collectd packets?

For example, I have the following plugins activated:

1. df
2. load
3. network
4. ping
5. swap
6. memory

I have an interval of ten seconds. I would like to find out the size of the collectd packets sent to the host system after every ten seconds.

Comment: @ardent-coder: FYI: The previous edit was in error. Collectd referred to the [collectd logging daemon](https://collectd.org/), not a spelling error of “collected” as proposed by the edit. I’ve changed this back, but kept the other edits.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Good job, the other edits were all good  improvements that I overlooked the tiny "collectd"